# Crc32 Compatibility between .NET and php

Tags: php, .net, checksum, crc32

i try to calculate checksum in `.net` in order to send data to `php` server. I use an webservice...

`php` use `Crc32` function [link](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.crc32.php)

the php checksum is only numbers...

and i use crc32 from [here](http://damieng.com/blog/2006/08/08/calculating_crc32_in_c_and_net)

my call is :

```
        [...]
        Crc32 checksum = new Crc32();
        foreach (byte b in crc32.ComputeHash(buffer))
                hash += b.ToString("x2").ToLower();
        // send data and checksum in webservice
```

UPDATE EXAMPLE

for a file (cv.txt) with this content : `Hello word !`

the checksum .NET is `fca641d7`

and the php checksum is `1016497679`

and it's not the same output... Php cannot read the data because the checksum is different

Someone know how to do ?

UPDATE 2 [LINK FILE CV.TXT](http://ul.to/v36axgjj)  password : 'cv'
(without quote)

Thanks !

Comment: How about you add some example output from each? Some of us can't run C code inside our heads.

Comment: I cannot duplicate either of your CRCs.  Please very carefully verify your example, and indicate if there is a new line after the phrase, and if so, if the new line is a line feed or a carriage return and a line feed.  Did you mean "word" or "world"?  Is there a space before the exclamation mark?

Comment: i added the file for download password = cv (see post update)

Comment: Something is wrong with how you are providing cv.txt data to the crc, or how you are interpreting the output.  The standard CRC32 of cv.txt is 8183c22c in hex or 2172895788 in decimal.  That doesn't match _either_ of your results.

Answer (score 0):

The CRC is a number, not a string.  You can use printf to show it in hexadecimal, e.g. "%'08x".

Comment: i added an example with the output (php and .net) thank for your reply